# AJAX with PHP debug

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What I am creating looks like this:

[image]

The buttons `Last Week` and `Next Week`, the `input` area and the `boxes` are meant to retrieve the date they have written in them as the selected day.

**Problem:** the 'Next Week' button is having a weird behaviour.

*This is what show up first when one click on it:* **(it's great)**
[image]

This is what happens after: **(it's not defining as date, the one that's being alerted)**
[image]
**The date selected and alerted is not the one that gets rendered.**

Instead, **it selects the date appended after running the script (so, it selects 7 days afer).**

**The Ajax:**

```
function foooo2(ctrl) {
        var mydate = extractContent(document.getElementsByClassName('herecode2')[0].innerHTML);
        alert(mydate);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/buttons_past_script.php',
            data: ({dates1: mydate}),
                dataType : 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.past_button').html(data);
              //  alert(data);
                $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/buttons_next_script.php',
            data: ({dates2: mydate}),
                dataType : 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.next_button').html(data);
              //  alert(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/boxes_buttons_script.php',
                    data: ({dates3: mydate}),
                        dataType : 'html',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('.caixas').html(data);
                     //   alert(data);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '/events_script.php',
                            data: ({dates4: mydate}),
                                dataType : 'html',
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('.results-ajax').html(data);
                          //  alert(data);
                            }
                        });//end of forth ajax call
                    }
                });//end of third ajax call
                }
            });//end of second ajax call
            }
        });//end of first ajax call
   }
```

**The PHP for the next button:**

```
<?php
    // Include and instantiate the class.
    require_once 'helpers/Mobile-Detect-2.8.24/Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    $dias= $_POST["dates2"];
    $first_date2 = strtotime($dias);
    $nweek_date = strtotime('+7 day', $first_date2);
    $nday_date = strtotime('+1 day', $first_date2);

    // Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
        echo '<div class="day-after col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" onclick="foooo2(this)" class="btn btn-default herecode2">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">'.date('m/d/y', $nday_date).'</span>
                    </button>
                </div>';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="next-week col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <button type="button" onclick="foooo2(this)" class="btn btn-gray btn-default herecode2">
                     Next Week <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">'.date('m/d/y', $nweek_date).'</span>
                    </button>
                </div>';
    }

    ?>
```

**Note:** This info should be ok for the help. If you need any other info just let me know.

Comment: `extractContent($(this).html());` try this instead and check out;

Comment: doesn't work. Makes sense because how could it recognize what is this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it by adding an id to span in the PHP code:

```
Next Week <span id="nextdate" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">'.date('m/d/y', $nweek_date).'</span>
```

then, instead of:

`var mydate = extractContent(document.getElementsByClassName('herecode2')[0].innerHTML);`

you can use :

`var mydate = $("#nextdate").html();`

Comment: true that.

The index is the constant `dates2`. But since that is likely undefined, PHP will often just convert it to the string `dates2` and log a warning message.

That's why in Eclipse is not even giving an error.
Thanks for that sharp eye. Still this won't solve the problem

Comment: check my updated answer. It appears that you are sending a string "Next Week 03/30/17", instead of just "03/30/17".